# Is it possible to take memory from std::string(like string move ctor does)?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

If I have my internal class that is my own version of `vector<char>` (I control the source) and for the sake of example I can not change it to be `std::string` is there a way to steal memory from `std::string`, just like move constructor of `std::string` does.

So something like this:

```
std::string str{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstu"};
MyVectorCharClass mvc(std::move(str)); // Constructor takes memory from str
```

I think I heard of some future proposals to add `.release()` to `std::string` or `std::vector` but I am talking about present time.

Comment: eh? but then str becomes an invalid string, do you really want that?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you reinvent the wheel regarding the vector class? `std::vector` is standardized in all C++ standard libraries, your vector class isn't.

Comment: Maybe some performance considerations? Specific usage cases? Most likely a "learning purposes" or something. However, although in 95% of all cases, writing all these "strings" and "dynamic_arrays" is a nonsense, sometimes it's necessary. Especially if you have, for example, a lot of copies and your profiler tells you, that `string::string(const string&)` is called so many times, that uint64_t was too small to hold the counting result...

Comment: There's [N4359](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4359.pdf) to add `release()` to `vector`. What's the proposal for `string`?

Comment: @Barry Probably it will be applied to both at the same time. `std::string` was designed to behave very similarly to `std::vector<char>`. Btw, I would be vary glad - such `release()` could often save you from doing unnecessary `memcpy`s.

Comment: Joachim like I said : "and for the sake of example " - I am just trying to learn.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek: `std::string` is not a container. It is in some sense very different from a vector. For example, swapping two vectors guarantees validity of iterators and references, whereas no such guarantee exists for strings. Strings are not required to allocate any memory at all.

Comment: N4359 will need a hell lot more work, thanks to all the fun with allocators. Howard Hinnant has a nice sketch [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/H2-dd8sFAKA/twhEhEvOA9IJ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The buffer that `std::string` manages is private to it. You can access it via `&str[0]`, but the `string` will still own it and will destroy it when it goes out of scope. You have no way of telling `str` that it now owns a different buffer, or to set its underlying buffer to `nullptr`, or any other way of making it *not* `delete` that buffer.

That's `std::string`'s job. It owns its buffer and it's not going to give it up.