# How to efficiently move underlying data from std::string to a variable of another type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

EDIT: Sorry everyone, I don't think this toy example really reflected my problem. What I should have asked is if there is a way to release a std::string object's buffer. There is not, and that makes sense. Thanks!

Suppose I have the following (broken) code:

```
void get_some_data(MyCustomContainer& val)
{
    std::string mystr = some_function();
    val.m_data = &mystr[0];
}
```

This won't work, because the memory pointed by `mystr` is freed at the end of `get_some_data`, and the memory referenced by val.m_data will be invalid.

How can I tell a std::string "Don't free your memory buffer at your destructor!" ? I don't want to copy the data. The MyCustomerContainer object will handle the memory free-ing at its destructor.

Comment: This is how stack allocation works.

Comment: When do you want the memory buffer of `std::string` to be freed then? Are you ok with a memory leak?

Comment: Where is this data going, and is it expected to be dynamically allocated?

Comment: I smell [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You can't suppress `std::string`'s destruction of it's underlying data. You can move it from a `std::string` to another `std::string` though.

Comment: erip- I am concerned with the buffer the string maintains a pointer to. I believe that memory will be allocated at runtime on the free store, not the stack.

Rakete- this is a toy example. In reality, I want to move the pointer to another object that will handle the free-ing.

Comment: Can't you return `std::string`?

Comment: just make get_some_data return a string

Comment: Make m_data a std::string. The solution is **allways** the same.

Comment: This gets a bit complicated when you add in SSO. You can't really seize an SSO buffer.

Comment: Hi everyone, I edited the question for clarity. Is there a way I can make this work, without changing the structure of MyCustomerContainer or the return value of the function, and iwthout copying the data?

Comment: **NOOOOOOOOOHHHHH**

Comment: So, why can't you make `m_data` a `std::string`?

Comment: How will the MyCustomerContainer object even know how to delete the std::string's member buffer?  There isn't a `std::string::oh_by_the_way_delete_this_buffer_for_me(m_data);` for it to use.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31767209/is-it-possible-to-take-memory-from-stdstringlike-string-move-ctor-does

Comment: If `MyCustomContainer` eventually performs any deallocation on the pointer, then you cannot use `std::string` but have to pass a pointer returned by a matching allocation function (`new`, `new[]`, `malloc` or whatever). However, your top priority should be to remove or change `MyCustomContainer` so that you can just use `std::string` without such headaches.

Comment: Why don't you post your `MyCustomContainer`? What is the type of `m_data`? Is it supposed to keep data alive? If so it shouldn't be a raw pointer.

Comment: Have `some_function()` return a `std::string*` (best done with a smart pointer) and make `m_data` the same.

Comment: This is actualy an excelent question that point out a mistake in the STL design that could be easily solved using modern C++. There are [guys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNXyNa6kf4k) out there working on it.

Comment: @Oliv: What mistake in the "STL design" would that be? You don't expect us to watch a one-hour video on YouTube just to find out, do you?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Viewing this entire may not be enough to grasp the concept. Otherwise it would have been implemented long time ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this without breaking the rules. The `std::string` class is not allowed to release its ownership explicitly. In fact, a `std::string` might not even have any memory allocated due to SBO optimization:

```
std::string str1 = "not allocating";
std::string str2 = "allocating on the heap, the string is too large";
```

This behavior is completely platform- and implementation-dependent. If a string doesn't allocate its buffer on the heap, the data is placed on the stack, which doesn't need de-allocation.

```
{
    std::string str1 = "not allocating";
} // no buffer freed
```

So even if there were a way to tell the string not to de-allocate its buffer, there is no way to tell if the buffer is managed on the heap or not.

Even if there were a way to tell if the string uses the stack, you'd have to allocate a buffer in place as a class member **and copy its content**.

The idea of transferring a string's data and stealing its ownership over that string's memory resource is fundamentally broken as you can't get away without copying, simply because there might be no ownership to steal.

---

What I recommend is for you to copy the string content in all cases if you don't want to change how `MyCustomContainer` works:

```
void get_some_data(MyCustomContainer& val)
{
    std::string mystr = some_function();
    val.m_data = new char[mystr.size()];
    std::memcpy(val.m_data, mystr.data(), mystr.size());
}
```

In contrast, if you allow `MyCustomContainer` to store a `std::string`, you could actually get away without copying when a buffer is allocated by moving the string:

```
void get_some_data(MyCustomContainer& val)
{
    // let m_data be a std::string
    val.m_data = some_function();

    // The above is equivalent to this:
    // std::string mystr = some_function();
    // val.m_data = std::move(mystr);
}
```

Moving a string will invoke move assignation. With move assignation, the string implementation will transfer the ownership of the `mystr`'s buffer into `m_data`. This will prevent any additional allocation.

If `mystr` didn't allocate, then the move assignment will simply copy the data (so no allocation there, either).

Answer (score 4):

The right way to fix this problem is:

```
class MyCustomContainer {
public:
  std::string m_data;
};

void get_some_data(MyCustomContainer& val) {
  val.m_data = some_function();
}
```

The `get_some_data` could even be made into a member function, which would make the usage even easier at the callsite, and perhaps allow `m_data` to be private instead of exposed.

Answer (score 3):

If .m_data  is an std::string you can take advantage of std::string's move-assignment operator:

```
val.m_data = std::move(mystr);
```

If m_data is not an std::string you are pretty much out of luck, the internal buffer is inaccessible (as it should be).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.  `std` containers will only give up their managed memory (and then only sometimes) to `std` containers of the same type.

For string this would be impossible regardless, as most implementations do a short string optimization and store short strings internally.

You could throw the std string into a global buffer somewhere and reap it at cleanup, but that gets insanely complex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use this code that causes Undefined Behavior, so it should not be used, but if you are working on some toy project of your own that will be quickly abandoned you can see if it works for you.

```
// REQUIRES: str is long enough so that it is using heap,
// std::string implementation does not use CoW implementation...
// ...
char* steal_memory(string&& str){
    alignas(string) char buff[sizeof(string)];
    char* stolen_memory = const_cast<char*>(str.data());
    new(buff) string(move(str)); 
    return stolen_memory;
}
```

If you want to handle short string you should add malloc and copy from buffer for that case.

Main idea here is to use placement new that takes the ownership from our input string, and not calling the destructor on string in buff. No destructor means no calls to free, so we can steal memory from the string.

Unfortunately const_cast is UB in this case so like I said you should never use this code in serious code.

Answer (score -3):

You can do `mystr` `static`

```
void get_some_data(MyCustomContainer& val)
{
    static std::string mystr;

    mystr = some_function();
    val.m_data = &mystr[0];
}
```

but, in this way, you have only one `mystr` for all `get_some_data()` calls; so

```
get_some_data(mcc1);
get_some_data(mcc2);

// now both `mcc1.m_data` and `mcc2.m_data` point to the same value,
// obtained from the second `some_function()` call
```

If you can compile-time enumerate the calls to `get_some_data()`, you can differentiate your `mystr` using a template index

```
template <std::size_t>
void get_some_data(MyCustomContainer& val)
{
    static std::string mystr;

    mystr = some_function();
    val.m_data = &mystr[0];
}

get_some_data<0U>(mcc1);
get_some_data<1U>(mcc2);

// now `mcc1.m_data` and `mcc2.m_data` point to different values
```